# Programmatically evaluate a list of functions in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I am trying figure out how to programmatically evaluate a list of functions.

Lets say that I have this code:

```
(defn foo
  []
  (println "foo"))

(defn bar
  []
  (println "bar"))

(def funcs [foo bar] )
```

I want execute all functions of `funcs` in a programmatically way.

I am tried use `eval`, but no succcess.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `for` if you want the return values, and are OK with lazy evaluation (your functions are not guaranteed to be called until you access the return value), and `doseq` if you don't need the values and are doing this for immediate side effects.

```
(doseq [f [foo bar]]
  (f))

(def fs
  (for [f [foo bar]]
    (f)))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `juxt`:

```
((apply juxt funcs))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply map over the functions with a call:

```
(map #(%) funcs)
```

[`doall`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doall) and [`dorun`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/dorun) can be used to force effects. `doall` retains results, while `dorun` just returns `nil`.

```
(defn foo [] :foo) ; no side-effects
(doall (map #(%) [foo foo]))
;=> (:foo :foo)

(defn print-foo [] (println (foo))) ; with side-effects
(dorun (map #(%) [print-foo print-foo]))
;=> :foo
;   :foo
;   nil
```